# java get class field value everytime its used

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to check for sum of cartitems price everytime cart class is called, so if coupon minCartPrice is higher than sum of cartitems price, then coupon will be set to null...

```
    @Entity
    public class Cart {
    
        @Id
        @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<CartItem> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();
        @OneToOne
        @JsonIgnore
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        private User user;
        @OneToOne
        private Coupon coupon;
        public Cart() {
        }
    }
```

.

```
@Entity
public class Coupon {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal discount = new BigDecimal(0);
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private DISCOUNT discountType;
    private BigDecimal minCartPrice= new BigDecimal(0);
    private Boolean isEnabled;
    public Coupon() {
    }
}
```

.

```
        BigDecimal sum= cartItems.stream()
                .map(CartItem::getPrice)
                .reduce(BigDecimal::add)
                .get();
```

Is something like this possible?
I have tried to check for it in default constructor, but every field is null right there, so i think im missing something..

Comment: You need to retrieve the entity first and then you could check the sum in a method for adding a cart item, like `Cart#addCartItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options you can take,

1. Since this is cart until checkout you have to update each and every time you add items to cart. You can check the total number when you add items to the cart and check the condition of the Coupon.
2. If you are assigning Coupon at checkout the cart you don't need to worry about the total each and every time you add items to cart. If that kind of scenario you can check the validity of the Coupon when you assigning the coupon to the cart.
3. (Optional) If you have more reasons to retrieve total for each time you retrieve cart data from the database then you can create a getter method inside the entity class and use it whenever you want.